# Quitar el geolocalizador y mostrar solo el listado de ubicaciones

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

Tengo el siguiente `script` que obtiene un `JSON` de una `API` y luego marca en el mapa los lugares con los `Markers`, pero necesito que se puedan listar sin el geolocalizador, al eliminar la función no me mustra nada en el mapa.

```
const getLocations = () => {
fetch('https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/g373-n3yy.json')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(locations => {
    let locationsInfo = []
    
    locations.forEach(location => {
        let locationData = {
            position:{lat:location.punto.coordinates[1],lng:location.punto.coordinates[0]},
            name:location.nombre_sede                
        }
        locationsInfo.push(locationData)
    })
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((data)=>{
            let currentPosition = {
                lat: data.coords.latitude,
                lng: data.coords.longitude
            }
            dibujarMapa(currentPosition, locationsInfo)
        })
    }
})
}

const dibujarMapa = (obj, locationsInfo) => {
let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
    zoom: 4,
    center: obj
})

let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: obj,
    title: 'Tu ubicacion'
})
marker.setMap(map)

let markers = locationsInfo.map(place => {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: place.position,
        map: map,
        title: place.name
    })
})
}
window.addEventListener('load',getLocations)
```

Yo he intentado lo siguiente:

```
const getLocations = () => {
fetch('https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/g373-n3yy.json')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(locations => {
    let locationsInfo = []
    
    locations.forEach(location => {
        let locationData = {
            position:{lat:location.punto.coordinates[1],lng:location.punto.coordinates[0]},
            name:location.nombre_sede                
        }
        locationsInfo.push(locationData)
    })

    dibujarMapa(locationsInfo)
})
}

const dibujarMapa = (locationsInfo) => {
let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
    zoom: 4
})

let markers = locationsInfo.map(place => {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: place.position,
        map: map,
        title: place.name
    })
})

marker.setMap(map)
}
window.addEventListener('load',getLocations)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te faltaría agregar el parámetro `center`, que según la [documentación](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview#MapOptions) es un parámetro requerido en `google.maps.Map`.

```js
const dibujarMapa = (locationsInfo) => {
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {        // <-- Faltaría center aquí
        lat: 7.56,
        lng: -75.768
      }, 
      zoom: 4
    })
```

Comment: Sí cóloco manualmente la latitud y longitud en el center como suguieres funciona, pero debe ser tomado de la lectura, al menos el primero... Porque lás coordenadas cambiarán, hice esto pero no funcionó `center: position`

Comment: No debería ser `locationsInfo[0].position` ? En el caso de centrar respecto del primer punto.

Comment: Listo! gracias. Sí cierto, se me pasó... Muchas gracias!